# PHP: Get a dynamic number of html input fields

Tags: php, html, input

This may be very obiouvs and simple, but I haven't used it, how can I get a from PHP a dynamic number of input fileds of the same type?

I have a situation where I'd like do make a dynamic number of inputs to send to the PHP page like this:

With jQuery I can add these inputs to increase or decrease the number of characters:

```
<!-- value is the character id -->
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="character" value="1256"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="character" value="85"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="character" value="901"></td></tr>
<tr><td>etc...</td></tr>
```

And I have a input submit at the end of the table to send data to my `php` page, how can I do to get all these characters? Should I do something directly with `AJAX` or can I handle it via `$_POST` variables?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Include empty array accessors in the name of your field:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="character[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="character[]" value="2">
```

Then access the post parameter as an array in php like:

```
foreach($_POST["character"] as $char) { … }
```

Comment: It's fantastic. I love it. Thank you!